# PostGIS Intersection of multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgis

In my postGIS DB, I need to create a new layer from the intersection of multiple polygons layers, while maintaining all fields (or Columns) from all layers (or tables) ==> in the output table, I need all columns for the 3 input tables

I believe it has to include ST_Intersects, but I am unable to find the correct syntax. Can you help me designing the SQL command line, knowing the following generic table names:

```
- TableA (with the columns: GeomA (geometry), ColumnA1, ColumnA2)
- TableB (with the columns: GeomB (geometry), ColumnB1)
- TableC (with the columns: GeomC (geometry), ColumnC1)
```

All geometry fields from TableA,TableB and TableC are in the same projection.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For clarity, since "interaction with multiple polygons layers" is a bit vague, it could mean:

- you want to find all polygons from A that intersect with a polygon from B and a polygon from C
- or A with B, B with C
- or A with B, A with C and B with C

For simplicity let us assume the first scenario, and I presume the others will be pretty easy to deduce:

```
 select A.*, B.*, C.*
 from A, B, C
 where st_intersects(A.geomA, B.geomB) = true
   and st_intersects(A.geomA, C.geomC) = true
```

[EDIT] Not just finding the rows, but if the intersection itself is important we can do the following (in the simple case of two geometries intersecting)

```
 select A.*, B.*, st_intersection(A.geomA, B.geomB) as geomAB
 from A, B
 where st_intersects(A.geomA, B.geomB) = true
```

I simplified the case because if A intersects with B, and A intersects with C, it is not even sure those two intersections intersect again and have a result.

If we suppost A intersects with B, B with C and C with A then we should have a intersection imho. So that would look like:

```
 select A.*, B.*, C.*, st_intersection(A.geomA, st_intersection(B.geomB, C.geomC)) as geomABC
 from A, B, C
 where st_intersects(A.geomA, B.geomB) = true
   and st_intersects(A.geomA, C.geomC) = true 
   and st_intersects(B.geomB, C.geomC) = true
```

Comment: I want to create new polygons in a new table (I called it output table on 1st post) which are defined by the intersected area of polygons from TableA,B,C. st_intersects is maybe not the right function to use. Is it clearer ? If you are familiar with Qgis, the function is named "Intersect" under the Vector Geoprocessing tools menu - I want to do the same (if possible using 3 tables at once, but if there is a solution with two, I can just run it twice).

Comment: Not sure how you would define the intersection, and even if there is a intersection if there are three tables (I mean A intersects B and A intersects C, but do those two intersections intersect each other??), but for two it is pretty simple. So I added that example. Then I extended the query that _should_ work for three intersecting geometries.